# How to send an string to server using fetch API

Tags: javascript, rest, go, fetch

I am using the `fetch` API to make a `POST` request to my server written in Go...

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080', {
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        image:"hello"
    })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log("response");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

On my Go server I am receiving the `POST`...

```
type test_struct struct {
    Test string
}

func GetImage(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    var t test_struct

    if req.Body == nil {
        http.Error(rw, "Please send a request body", 400)
        return
    }
    err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&t)
    fmt.Println(req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(rw, err.Error(), 400)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(t.Test);
}
```

The `POST` request is made. I know this because `fmt.Println(t.Test)` is printing a blank line to the console.

`fmt.Println(req.Body)` gives me `<nil>` in the console.

The only error message I get is from the fetch API. It prints to the console the following error...

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

this is coming from the `.catch` declaration.

In short, how can I receive the string on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you decode `req.Body`, you can't read again the request body, because it's already read the buffer, for that reason you're getting the message `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. If you want to use the value on `req.Body`, you must to save the content of `req.Body` in a variable, something like this.

```
buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
// check err for errors when you read r.Body
reader := bytes.NewReader(buf)
err = json.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&t)
fmt.Println(string(buf))
if err != nil {
    http.Error(rw, err.Error(), 400)
    return
}
```

Also, your JSON is like `{"image":"hello"}`, so your struct should be:

```
type test_struct struct {
    Test string `json:"image"`
}
```

If you want to map the `image` value into `Test`